# How to include template with css to all pages on website

Tags: php, html, css, templates

I have created a template.html that contains the header, navigation and footer, and i want to include that to all my other pages: html/php files on the website without having to copy all the code to all other files.
Is there an easy way to do this? or is there a more proper way to handle this?
I've already tried to require the page with php, but it didn't take any of the styling.

UPDATE: I ended up switching to using include function.
I needed to use php in my html and if you echo out php script the code is just gonna be commented.
I found that the best was using include for head, header(and nav) and footer.
However to avoid making multiple opening and closing html tags, I formatted it this way:

```
head: <html><head>
-content for head
header: </head><body><header></header>
-content between header and footer
footer: <footer></footer></body></html>
```

Comment: You could potentially make a huge `div` for your body with a jQuery `.load()` function. Not the most elegant, but effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd organize my different scripts so that they are all called from an index.php (if not already done). Then, just before the logic which constructs the pages I'd include the header and nav, and the footer after.

here's a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- here your header --></head>
<body>
~
<!-- here your navigation? -->
~
</body>
</html>
```

I put those '~' to be able to explode it:

```
$template = explode('~',file_get_contents('template.html'))
// that way we have our code in an array we can easily use for header, navig and footer
$html = $template[0]; // header
$html.= $template[1]; // nav

switch($action) {
case 'foo':
  $html.= file_get_contents('foo.html');// just add directly html content
  break;                                // careful that it does not have <body> tags
case 'bar':
  require_once('bar.php');
  $html.= showBar(); // if you have a function in your script, you can add it to your page that way
  break;
}

$html.= $template[2]; // footer
```

if your other scripts echo out content directly, change `$html.=` with `echo`

Comment: Worked pretty well, however my template.html has a separate file for styles template_style.css(I can just copy the styles directly into the template.html), but I also have a Spry collapsible panel that didn't show up.
Should I include the .js and .css from the spry panel separately?

Comment: My mistake, the template.html was placed in a separate folder and that messed up the references to the style sheet and the spry panel.

Answer (score 2):

Well you put your :

header in one file such as header.php
footer in one file such as footer.php
and so on.

Then in your other .php files you just call the include function giving your header/footer path.